# show input fields instead of text when you click an "edit" link

Tags: jquery, xhtml, click

I am currently creating a backend. What I need is some jquery to insert some different form fields. I can for example have this code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        Name
    </div>
    <div>
        Type
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code needs to get converted so the Name and Type text is insted the values of two input fields when I click a.edit

EDIT:

I've tried this code - but when I click "a.ff-save" it does not alert??? What is my problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    var this_form_id = $("input#form_id").val();
    $("#formfield-list div.formfield-ff:odd").css('background', '#f6f6f6');


    $("a.ff_add").click( function() {
        var name_val = $("input#new_field_name").val();
        var type_val = $("input#new_field_type").val();
        var demand_val = $("input#new_field_demand").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{pref_folder}/admix/forms/addFormField",
            data: ({ form_id: this_form_id, field_name: name_val, field_type: type_val, field_demand: demand_val }),
            success: function(text) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "{pref_folder}/admix/forms/getFormFields",
                    data: { form_id: this_form_id },
                    success: function(t) {
                        $("#formfield-list").empty().append(t);
                        $("#formfield-list div.formfield-ff:odd").css('background', '#f6f6f6');
                    },
                    dataType: "html"
                });


                $(".add-succes-message").empty().append('<div class="msg">'+text+'</div>');
                $(".add-field-row").slideUp(500, function(){
                    $(".add-field-row").slideDown(500);
                }).delay(3500);
                $(".add-succes-message").slideDown(500, function(){
                    $(".add-succes-message").slideUp(500);
                }).delay(3500);

            },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: "html"
        });
    });

    $("a.ff-save").click(function (){
        alert("ok");
    });

    $("a.ff-edit").click(function (){
        var fid = $(this).prev().val();

        var nameValue = $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-name").html().trim();
        var typeValue = $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-type").html().trim();
        var demandValue = $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-demand").html().trim();
        var typeInt;

        if( typeValue == "Tekstfelt, 1 linje" )
        {
            typeInt = 1;
        } else {
            typeInt = 0;
        }


        $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-name").html('<input type="text" name="name" class="jq-input" value="'+nameValue+'" />');
        $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-type").html('<input type="text" name="type" class="jq-input" value="'+typeInt+'" />');
        if( demandValue == "Ja")
        {
            $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-demand").html('<input type="checkbox" name="demand" class="jq-input" value="" checked="checked" />');
        } else {
            $("#ff-"+fid+" div.ff-demand").html('<input type="checkbox" name="demand" class="jq-input" value="" />');
        }

        $("#ff-"+fid+" .ff-edit, #ff-"+fid+".ff-delete").hide();
        $("#ff-"+fid+" div:last").html('<a href="#" class="ff-save">Save</a>');
    });

    $("a.ff-delete").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this jQuery plugin. It exactly does what you are looking for.

> **[JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)**

If you are not inclined towards using the plugin, then try the code below:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label class="editable">Name</label>
        <input class="editable" type="text" name="name" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="editable">Type</label>
        <input class="editable" type="text" name="type" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".edit").click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var text = $this.text();
            if(text=="Edit"){
                $this.text("Cancel");
            }
                        else{
                             $this.text("Edit");
                        }
            $(".editable").toggle();
        });

        $("input.editable").change(function(){
            $(this).prev().text($(this).text());

        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

To bind the click event handler to the anchor element use the live function of jQuery.
e.g:

```
$("a.ff-save").live("click", function (){         
 alert("ok");     
});
```

Comment: Yes in some way - but I need both text strings to get converted to fields and when you then click "save" it saves the edits made in both fields.

Comment: @Dennis: Can you post the Full HTML. Are you binding the click event to .ff-save in the ready event handler? Are you adding the .ff-save dynamically to the DOM? If yes then you should use live.

Comment: @Cybernate: EDIT: Now I have added the whole JS/Jquery - is that ok?
....... Original msg: I add a.ff-save here:
$("#ff-"+fid+" div:last").html('<a href="#" class="ff-save">Save</a>');

I am using a framework with pseudo-variables, so it can be a lot of lines.

Comment: @Dennis: Since you are adding the ff-save dynamically to bind the click event handler you should use live function. e.g: $("a.ff-save").live("click", function (){         alert("ok");     });

Comment: @Dennis: Also added the formatted code for the live function to original post. Check it.

Comment: @Cybernate: It is working. The only things I need to add now is:
Only ONE line may have input fields shown. And the edit-database-logic :-) .. Thank you. I have accepted your answer - but maybe I will make a question or two regarding to the two last things ;)

Answer (score 7):

I tried a few different approaches and this is what I came up with:

HTML:

```
<span class="subject">
    <span class="text"> subject </span>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="subject" val="subject" hidden/>
</span>
```

Jquery:

```
function showInput(){
    $(this).off('click');
    $(this).siblings('input').each(function(){$(this).show();});
    $(this).siblings('input').focus();
    $(this).hide();
}
function hideInput(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('span').show();
    $(this).siblings('span').click(showInput);
}
$(function(){
    $('.text').click(showInput);
    $('.input').blur(hideInput);
}
```

Simply put when you click on the given text it will turn into an input box and when the input box loses focus then it turns back into regular text.

I also made the show/hide functions separate callable functions so I could reset the click listener within the hideInput function.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This is a great example of a great answer.  Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this at work, here was my solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='name' class='text'>
        Name
    </div>
    <div id='type' class='text'>
        Type
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function StartEditState() {
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('a.edit').unbind('click').click(SaveEditState).html('Save'); //this changes edit button save button
    container.find('div.text').each(function() {
        $(this).html('<input class="new_val" type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" /><input class="orig_val" type="hidden" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />'); // this creates a hidden with the old value and an input that they can change
    });
    return false;
}
```

To save the values you just need to do this `$('#name input.new_val').val()` (for name, use `#type` for type) or to return to the original values use `$('#name input.orig_val').val()`

Hope you like it.